# PyCryptodome RSA encryption

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, python-cryptography, pycryptodome

I am trying to use the pycryptodome example of encrypting a file with an RSA key. The example is as follows

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

file_out = open("encrypted_data.bin", "wb")

recipient_key = RSA.import_key(open("receiver.pem").read())
session_key = get_random_bytes(16)

# Encrypt the session key with the public RSA key
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
file_out.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))

# Encrypt the data with the AES session key
cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)
[ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ]
```

And the error I receive is

> AttributeError: module 'Crypto.PublicKey.RSA' has no attribute 'import_key'

I found another thread where this error was identified as a version problem with pyCrypto but I am trying to use PyCryptodome and I do have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The method `import_key` was added in [PyCryptodome v3.4](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/master/Changelog.rst).
If you get that error message, it means you are in reality using PyCrypto or an older version of PyCryptodome.

Comment: How do I make sure I am using the correct version and not PyCrypto?

Comment: You can check the `Cipher.version_info` tuple. PyCryptodome will have version >=3.0.0. Or you can install `pycryptodomex`, which is still PyCryptodome but under the `Cryptodome` package (instead of `Crypto`, to avoid the collision).